# Python, extracting numbers from Excel column and write as output

Tags: python, regex, excel

Trying to extract the number from columns in an Excel file, and write them into the next columns.

Matching criteria: any number of length five, either started with “PB” or not

I’ve limited the length of the number match to five however there are a “16” extracted (row#2, column D)

[image]

How I can improve it? Thank you.

```
import xlwt, xlrd, re
from xlutils.copy import copy 

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Documents\\num.xlsx")
old_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

wb = copy(workbook) 
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)

number_of_ships = old_sheet.nrows

for row_index in range(0, old_sheet.nrows):

    Column_a = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value   
    Column_b = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value

    a_b = Column_a + Column_b

    found_PB = re.findall(r"[PB]+(\d{5})", a_b, re.I)
    list_of_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', a_b)

    for f in found_PB:
        if len(f) == 5:
            sheet.write(row_index, 2, "";"".join(found_PB))

    for l in list_of_numbers:
        if len(l) == 5:
            sheet.write(row_index, 3, "";"".join(list_of_numbers))

wb.save("C:\\Documents\\num-1.xls")
```

Comment: If you use `\d+`, it will just extract 1+ digit chunks, so you have not restricted anything. If you need numbers after `PB`, write `PB`, not `[PB]` (a character class matching either `P` or `B`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you! could you please put this as an answer so that I can close it? Or 'd better to delete this question?

Comment: Well, I do not know how to answer it. What exactly do you need? What are the pattern requirements?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, your comment already answered it. I changed them to "found_PB = re.findall(r"PB+(\d{5})", a_b, re.I)" and "list_of_numbers = re.findall(r'\d{5}', a_b)". Problem solved!

Comment: That `PB+` does not work the way you think. It will match PB, PBB, PBBB, PBBBB, etc, and cannot match a number unless it starts with PB (or PBBBB,...) The `+` affects the previous character or group. If you want to modify both letter you may wrap them inside a group `(?:PB)`. Also `+` means 1 or more times. You'll probably want `*` (0 or more times) or even `?` (0 or 1 times)

Comment: Ok, I think I know the answer now.

Comment: @MarkK Please check [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52035118/3832970)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\d+` pattern matches any 1 or more digits, thus the `16` value is matched. Your `[PB]+` character class matches either `P` or `B` one or more times, so it restricts the digits to be preceded with either `P` or `B`. As you want to match any digits, you actually do not need that restriction (if an `A` can be preceded with something *optionally*, the restriction no longer makes sense).

You also seem to need to extract 5 digit string exactly, when no other digits precedes or follows them. You may do that with [`(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/J0akR7/1). The `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind makes sure there is no digit immediately to the left of the current location, `\d{5}` consumes 5 digits, and the `(?!\d)` negative lookahead makes sure there is no digit immediately to the right of the current location. That makes the `if len(l) == 5:` line redundant and you may omit the whole part of code related to `list_of_numbers`.

So, you may just use

```
import xlwt, xlrd, re
from xlutils.copy import copy 

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Documents\\num.xlsx")
old_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

wb = copy(workbook) 
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)

number_of_ships = old_sheet.nrows

for row_index in range(0, old_sheet.nrows):

    Column_a = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value   
    Column_b = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value

    a_b = Column_a + Column_b

    found_PB = re.findall(r"(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)", a_b)

    for f in found_PB:
            sheet.write(row_index, 2, "";"".join(found_PB))

wb.save("C:\\Documents\\num-1.xls")
```

Comment: but in case the cell contains more than 1 5-digits, how to catch them all? (for example, cell A2 is "PB65352, 456789")

Comment: @MarkK If you do not need a "digit boundary" check, remove `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/J0akR7/2). Then, the solution becomes too trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this: `^(?:PB)?\d{5}$`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8yw8T7/1/)**

**Explained:**

```
^           # Begin of line/string
  (?:       # Begin of group
     PB     #   Literal 'PB'
  )         # End of group
  ?         # Make the previous group optional (? means 0 or 1 times)
  \d{5}     # 5 digits
$           # End of line/string
```

It is important to use the `$`, since if you just wrote `^(?:PB)?\d{5}` you would match 6 digit numbers even if you wrote `\d{5}` this is because you would match the first five digits and you would stop there, without knowing if there are more digits.

If your data may start or end with spaces you may use this instead: `^\s*(?:PB)?\d{5}\s*$` It basically adds `\s*` at the beginning and the end of the regex. `\s*` means 0 or more spaces.

Comment: thank you for the sharing and help. would you mind I choose Wiktor Stribiżew's for his getting more upvotes? I can upvote yours too. :)

Comment: Just accept what works better for you, and upvote if it is useful for you :) @MarkK

Comment: sharing knowledge and help others is always lights in the learning world. you are superb, @Julio